# Temporary file with linux command output

Tags: c, linux, file, popen

I am struggling with popen() function to get output of linux commands. This function can save output in some pipe and it is possible to read it, but I want to specify name of temporary file. I was thinking about iterating through popen pipe and writing result into new file specified name, but it's probably not the most efficient. Is there any function or tricky way to do that more efficient?

Comment: if you want to put the result of commands into a file you do not need _popen_ just use _system_ to execute your command redirecting the output in your file (e.g. `system("command > file");` the goal of _popen_ is to read/write from/to command output/input without using a file

Comment: `popen` opens a pipe. Pipes are not files. They are unidirectional streams between the two processes and are buffered in memory only.

Comment: that's true, my mistake. I edited it ;)

Comment: Technically, on Linux, pipes *are* files. They're stored on a special internal-only fs `pipefs` that makes up its own root. This fun fact is an implementation detail that has exactly zero relevance to this question.

Comment: @thatotherguy The old `Unix` idea of "Everything is a file".  Taken to an even further extreme in `Plan 9 From Bell Labs`.

Comment: @thatotherguy Pipes are not files, they're just kernel buffers used to pass data between processes. You can read and write them using the same system calls as files, but they're not stored anywhere. Named pipes are filenames, but there's no storage associated with them, they just refer to the kernel data.

Comment: what you need is fork+exec with the child opening the file descriptor 1 to a file, as simple as that.

Comment: @Barmar On Linux, anonymous pipes are files in much the same sense that named pipes are. [Here's](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/da2577fe63f865cd9dc785a42c29c0071f567a35/fs/pipe.c#L1154) the source code for the special `pipefs` that stores them internally. It's not exposed as an enumerable tree to userspace, but it's still there.

Comment: @thatotherguy That's new to Linux, I think, it's not the way pipes have traditionally been implemented in Unix.

Comment: @Barmar Minix does the same thing so I'm guessing it's not new to Linux specifically, but it's most definitely an implementation detail and not a requirement to implement a Unix clone